# Wrong type casting in FOR-IN loop wrecks seemingly unrelated variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a simple stopwatch with State widget.

Initialize variables in State:

```
final laps = <int>[];
int milliseconds = 0;
```

milliseconds are updated in Timer every 0.1 seconds (after start button pressed):

```
setState((){
  milliseconds += 100;
});
```

lap method updates list of laps (after lap button is pressed, when timer is running):

```
setState((){
  laps.add(milliseconds);
});
```

And a method for displaying laps (running in build() on every setState):

```
for(int milliseconds in laps)
  Text(_format(milliseconds))
```

The question is, if I forget to do type casting in for-in method, like this:

```
for(milliseconds in laps)
```

this wrecks the timer, and it just stops incrementing. It keeps running but milliseconds are just stuck at last value when lap was pressed.
How so?
I thought milliseconds is one variable, and laps list is another and it's values are yet another variables...
This is confusing.

***DartPad with full code is
https://dartpad.dev/?id=09114fd8f5332610042b1af85afdcae8 and *without* type casting (laps not working version). To get it work add ***int** milliseconds* at line 149. It takes a minute to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when declaring a variable, you must either use `Type variableName = value;` or `var variableName = value` (you can also use `final variableName = value;` or `var variableName;` and I'm sure some others, but that's not the point).

when you do `for (milliseconds in laps)` you neither put the type nor add `var` or `final` keyword. This would give you an error if you had not declared the `milliseconds` variable before, because you have, it just assigns the value of each iteration to said variable, effectively breaking your code.

It's akin to this example

```
int i=183;
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
  print(i);
}
print(i);
```

If i run this code I get the following output:

```
0
1
2
2
```

If I add var, I get the following output:

```
0
1
2
183
```

So basically if you add `var` or `int` to the loop, you are redefining the variable inside the for-loop scope, if you don't you assign directly to the already existing variable, which in turn breaks the app.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks! So - for(milliseconds in laps) just assigns the last lap to current milliseconds.